# Implicit views in companion object

Tags: scala, implicit

I was reading Scala In Depth by Joshua D. Suereth, and came across the following code about implicit views in scala:

```
object test {
  trait Foo
  trait Bar
  object Foo {
    implicit def fooToBar(f : Foo) =  new Bar{ }
  }
}
```

Then define a method that requires a Bar as argument:

```
def bar(x : Bar) = println("bar")
```

Why the following works:

```
val f = new Foo{}
bar(f) // print "bar"
```

but

```
bar(new Foo{})
```

would cause the compiler to give type mismatch error:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : java.lang.Object with test.Foo
required: test.Bar
          bar(new Foo {})
              ^
```

Comment: I can't explain why, but `bar(new Foo{})` does work if you define the implicit conversion in a companion object of `Bar` instead of `Foo`.

Comment: Funny. This also compiles: `bar(new Foo{}: Foo)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's something about what you are doing:

```
new Foo {} // Anonymous subclass of Object with trait Foo
new Foo () // Foo
new Foo    // Foo
```

When you do something like `bar(new Foo {})`, the compiler doesn't know yet what you are doing -- it tries to find a `bar` method that will accept `new Foo {}`, but it doesn't know yet exactly what type `new Foo {}` is, because it depends on what `bar` is.

If you declare `val f = new Foo{}`, `f`'s type becomes fixed, which then helps the compiler find out what it should do about `bar`.

Comment: But the compiler did find the type to be `java.lang.Object with  test.Foo`.